# QtConsole Development

Tags: ipython, qtconsole

Is QtConsole developed by the ipython team?

I always assumed it was a nice little widget provided from Qt, implemented by iPy. If Qt merely provides a base widget, and all the terminal magic is part of the iPy effort, that changes things. Like seriously.

Im stuck in Windows for the foreseeable months and would like to help what I can. If QtConsole can polish a few minor issues and provide another moderate feature or two, I think it would be something to get pretty excited about if you are command-line junky with Windows as a roomate.

Comment: Its true that QTConsole is part of IPython but it is getting less love from Ipython team (sorry @minrk thats what  me and our team feels. we love IPy Qtconsole alot more than IPNotebook )  . Only 3-4 changes related to QTconsole within 2 months worries us a lot. Ipython team is focusing alot on Ipython Notebook , but we found it much less productive when coding vs QTConsole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QtConsole is part of IPython.  It is built on the QtRichTextWidget, but all of the console / terminally stuff is implemented [in IPython](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/tree/master/IPython/frontend/qt/).